# convert php array to javascript literal object

Tags: php, json

I have a php page which returns a php array as the following

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(10) "Ananindeua"
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Ananindeua"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(8) "An�polis"
    [0]=>
    string(8) "An�polis"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(8) "Anderson"
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Anderson"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(6) "Angers"
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Angers"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(9) "Angoul�me"
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Angoul�me"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cityName"]=>
    string(6) "Anshan"
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Anshan"
  }
}
```

I want to use this array in another page to do some ajax, and I want to encode the resulat into a JSON as the following :

```
{
    "cityName": "Anshan",
    "cityName": "Angoul�me",
    "cityName": "Anderson",
    "cityName": "An�polis",
    "cityName": "Ananindeua"
}
```

but Instead I get only one value, which is the last value :

```
{
    "cityName": "Anshan"
}
```

This is the code I tried :

```
<?php
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world", 'root', 'toor'); 
    $statement = $connexion->prepare("SELECT cityName FROM cities WHERE cityName LIKE '" . $_POST['cityName'] . "%'"); 
    $statement->execute();
    
    $resultats = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach($resultats as $city) {
        $output[key($city)] = current($city);
    }
    echo json_encode($output, 128);
?>
```

So how can I solve this problem ?

## Edit :

I tried to get only cities names, and push them into an array, when I do a `var_dump()` for this array this is what I get :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Ananindeua"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "An�polis"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Anderson"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Angers"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Angoul�me"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Anshan"
}
```

But when I did a `json_encode()` I don't get anything, so I tried to do a `var_dump(json_encode($output));` and I get this :

```
bool(false)
```

In the second time I tried to create a table manually :

```
$a = array("Ananindeua","Anápolis","Anderson","Angers","Angoulême","Anshan" );
```

and it worked.

But why the first array won't encode !

Comment: This is happening because a PHP array cannot contain the same key more than once.

So everytime you try to add a value from your loop, the previous instance of 'cityName' is replaced with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the table which I populate from database contains some accented characters, so the json_encode() failing.

The solution was to add `charset=UTF8` in the first parameter of the PDO instance.

```
$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=UTF8", 'root', 'toor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `array`'s key is same (`cityName`), so the value getting replaced on each assignment.

use a numeric array, or another method that differentiating the key

e.g.,

```
foreach($resultats as $city) {
    $output['cityName'][] = current($city);
}
```

output will be

```
{"cityName":
    [
    "Anshan",
    "Angoulme",
    "Anpolis"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say that it didn't work I get the alert box with an empty string

Comment: did you `var-dumped/printr()` the `$output`? and what  is the result?

Comment: I did a `var_dump($output);` and this is the result : `array(1) { ["cityName"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(10) "Ananindeua" [1]=> string(8) "Anápolis" [2]=> string(8) "Anderson" [3]=> string(6) "Angers" [4]=> string(9) "Angoulême" [5]=> string(6) "Anshan" } } `

Comment: so then `echo json_encode($output)` must produce the expected output, please paste the output after `json_encode($output)`

Comment: There is no output for the `json_encode($output);`, when I tried this `var_dump(json_encode($output));` I get : `bool(false)`

Comment: but i'm getting `{"cityName":["Ananindeua","An\u00e1polis","Anderson","Angers","Angoul\u00eame","Anshan"]}`, please check your code again.

`<?php
$output["cityName"]= array("Ananindeua","Anápolis","Anderson","Angers","Angoulême","Anshan" );
echo json_encode($output);
?>`

http://codepad.org/XbzvPDtk

Comment: When I create an array manually as you montioned it works, but when I populate my array with values from database, it won't work

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not valid/conceivable either as a PHP associative array or JSON because in both cases, you have duplicate keys.

You're just overwriting the `cityName` key with each iteration. Push to an array instead:

```
foreach($resultats as $city) {
    $output[] = current($city);
}
echo json_encode($output, 128);
```

Output:

```
[
    "Anshan",
    "Angoulme",
    "Anpolis"
]
```

Or if you want an object for each city, which is useful if you want other properties:

```
foreach($resultats as $city) {
    $output[] = array(
        'cityName' => current($city)
    );
}
echo json_encode($output, 128);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
       "cityName" : "Anshan",
    },
    {
       "cityName" : "Angoulme",
    },
    {
       "cityName" : "Anpolis"
    }
]
```

---

Side note: if you don't need the numerical keys from the PDO fetch call, consider using the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetch style, to bring back only associative keys:

```
$resultats = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post.

Comment: What are those special characters in the city names? Try removing them to see if it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

The json you're expecting doesn't look right. It should be:

```
[
    {"cityName": "Anshan"},
    {"cityName": "Angoul�me"},
    {"cityName": "Anderson"},
    {"cityName": "An�polis"},
    {"cityName": "Ananindeua"}
]
```

and to generate this you need code like this:

```
foreach($resultats as $city) {
    $item = new stdClass(); 
    $item.cityName = current($city);
    $output[] = item;
}
```

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post.

Comment: It looks like the json_encode is failing, so something is going wrong. Use jason_last_error http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php  to see what is going on